# как обратиться к данным json api, приложение на vue

Tags: json, vue.js, api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`let searchSymbol = '0XBTC';

let fullName = data2.find(((symbol) => {symbol["searchSymbol"] ===
searchSymbol;console.log(this);} ).FullName);

console.log(fullName);`

Comment: Подскажите как вывести значение FullName найденного объекта по значению Symbol

Comment: Ошибка есть TypeError: data2.find is not a function